Hive evaluating a string similar to Javascript eval()

I would like to have a query evaluating a string which is executable.
For example, in JavaScript we use `eval('2 + 2')` which will evaluate the string to 4.
How to do the same in Hive? Something similar to below:
Table1 will have transactional data and table2 will have flags and conditions columns.
Select a.*, b.result
from table1 a
left outer join table2 b on ( eval(b.condition) )

